# Not able to read the german umlaut(ä, ö, ü) from command line args in linux in java spring boot

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, hibernate, oop

When I tried to read the command line args then it gives me **`??`** this type of string instead of german umlaut.
I have tried

Convert from ISO to UTF-8

new String (args[0].getBytes(StandardCharset.ISO-8859-1)), StandardCharset.UTF-8);

Convert from ISO to UTF-8

new String (args[0].getBytes(StandardCharset.UTF-8)), StandardCharset.ISO-8859-1);

But it didn't work

Comment: Why don't you use UTF-8? And is your command line able to present the character correctly? Which charset does it use?

Comment: `args[0]` is already a `String`.

Comment: Default encoding is UTF-8, COMMAND LINE PRESENT THE CHARACTER CORRECTLY.